# Pushout on the following diagram

Tags: category-theory

I am going to describe the diagram since I do not know how to do them on latex. Say $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and we have $H\rightarrow G$ via inclusion (call this map $i$), and $H\rightarrow 1$ via the trivial map (call this map $z$). We want to find the pushout of it.

I think that the pushout will be $1$ because the map $f_1:G\rightarrow 1$ and the map $f_2:1\rightarrow 1$ are such that $f_2(z(h))=f_1(i(h))$ for all $h\in H$. Further, since $1$ is an initial object in the category of groups then we would be done.

Is the above correct?

Thanks.

Comment: yes this seems correct because the square commutes and the universal property is easily proved by uniqueness of maps from (since it's a colimit) the zero object. Oh I called 1 the zero object, note it's initial and terminal in Grp.

Comment: sorry I am wrong let me leave this comment up in case it is a common mistake.

Comment: This question is really old now, but I wanted to add a comment in case anyone else was as confused as I was by how this could be figured out easily (i.e. algorithmically). For me, the way I finally fully internalized this was by realizing that, in any category, the push-out of a diagram is always the injections of the disjoint union composed with the co-equalizer (up to isomorphism) If these objects exist. 

If you write it out in a diagram and then "simplify", this reduces to Shaun Ault's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the trivial group is not the pushout.  In the pushout diagram, $P$ is the pushout if whenever $Q$ is given such that $j_1\circ f = j_2 \circ g$, then there is a unique morphism $u$ that must also satisfy $j_1 = u \circ i_1$ and $j_2 = u \circ i_2$.

[image: pushout]

Thus, in your situation, the trivial group cannot be the pushout, since for any group $Q \neq 1$, with nontrival map $G \to Q$, that map cannot factor through the trivial map.  Instead, what you're looking for is the [amalgamated product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amalgamated_product#Generalization:_Free_product_with_amalgamation).  In your diagram, that would be the free product, $1 \ast G$, modulo the normal closure of $H$ (to account for the relations $i(h) = 1$ for $h \in H$).
This amounts to $G/\langle H\rangle$, where $\langle H \rangle$ is the normal closure of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: And in this case the colimit of the diagram coincides with the pushout, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the pushout is a type of colimit.